# Does anyone know what this probability question is asking?

Tags: probability

I have no idea what the first problem on this list is asking? The others I can figure our, but does anyone know what the first one is actually asking? If so, how would you set it up?

Nate can only invite 8 people to his birthday, but has 13 friends he’d like to invite.  Eight of his friends are boys and five are girls.  Three of the girls are roommates and must stay together.  If Dante randomly selects 8 people, determine the probability for each scenario.

1. Dante’s random selection is a valid outcome
2. Dante does not invite any girls
3. Dante invites an equal number of boys and girls

Comment: An outcome is valid if the three roommates are either all simultaneously invited or all simultaneously not invited.  An outcome is invalid if only one or two of the roommates are invited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample space: selections of eight from thirteen people; all outcomes uniformly probable, so probabilities are the count of favoured outcomes versus the total count.

Favoured outcomes:

- 1) the three roommates are either all among the selection, or none are.
- 2) no girls are selected, *all* eight boys are. (Automatically valid as three roommates are not boys.)
- 3) four boys are selected, four girls also: which either includes the three roommates, or excludes them (but note: there are only five girls, so...)

Comment: For number 3 I do not think it's a requirement for the selection to be valid. It's just asking what's the probability of 4 boys and 4 girls being selected.